# Could not save file on disk in controller

Tags: java, file, spring-mvc, spring-boot, multipartform-data

I have following controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/load_attachment")
    public DeferredResult uploadingPost(@RequestParam("attachment") MultipartFile[] uploadingFiles, @RequestParam("stoneId") String stoneId) throws IOException {
        logger.info("Upload {} files for stone: {}", uploadingFiles.length, stoneId);
        for (MultipartFile uploadedFile : uploadingFiles) {
            File file = new File(uploadedFile.getOriginalFilename());
            uploadedFile .transferTo(file);
            logger.info("path:{}", file.getAbsolutePath()); // I expect to find files here

        }
}
```

No exceptions happens but I could not find files on file system.

Comment: `File file = new File(uploadedFile.getOriginalFilename());` it won't refer to your local path

Comment: @Kalaiselvan A What???  inside File constructor exists normalizer

Comment: `uploadedFile.getOriginalFilename()` will return the file name right!. you should specify the full path

Comment: @Kalaiselvan A, **uploadedFile.getOriginalFilename()** will return string represents file name. I should not specify full path because I want to store file inside application folder

Comment: that's what I am asking server doesn't the application servers path so you need to specify it manually.

Comment: @gstackoverflow provide absolute(relative if you have server's path) path, `File file = new File("path/to/your/server/application/directory"+uploadedFile.getOriginalFilename());`

Answer (score 0):

In your case, Application server doesn't application server inside folder path so you should specify it manually!...

```
  for (MultipartFile uploadedFile : uploadingFiles) {
        File file = new File("path/to/your/server/application/directory"+uploadedFil‌e.getOriginalFilenam‌e());
        uploadedFile .transferTo(file);
        logger.info("path:{}", file.getAbsolutePath()); // I expect to find files here

    }
```

for further reference https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile&method=transferTo

Comment: **File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), uploadedFile.getOriginalFilename());**  works for me

Comment: But looks like I should not aware about server path

Comment: correct `user.dir` having folder path  and your appending your file name so it will works

Comment: `user.dir ` will return path of your `dir`

Comment: but **file.getAbsolutePath()** returns expected value

Comment: @gstackoverflow  it works properly but once it goes to client side it will cause path not found or something else. In your local system, you are trying to upload the file from your user directory so it won't throw any error.

Comment: can you clarify concept?